# What happens if I read a file without closing it afterwards?

Tags: python, file-io

I used to read files like this:

```
f = [i.strip("\n") for i in open("filename.txt")]
```

which works just fine. I prefer this way because it is cleaner and shorter than traditional file reading code samples available on the web (e.g. f = open(...) , for line in f.readlines() , f.close()).

However, I wonder if there can be any drawback for reading files like this, e.g. since I don't close the file, does Python interpreter handles this itself? Is there anything I should be careful of using this approach?

Comment: Sorry for bad title btw, I appreciate if someone with better English can fix it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the recommended way:

```
with open("filename.txt") as f:
    lines = [line.strip("\n") for line in f]
```

The other way may not close the input file for a long time.  This may not matter for your application.

The `with` statement takes care of closing the file for you.  In CPython, just letting the file handle object be garbage-collected should close the file for you, but in other flavors of Python (Jython, IronPython, PyPy) you definitely can't count on this.  Also, the `with` statement makes your intentions very clear, and conforms with common practice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Btw, since you said "recommended way"; where can I find/read about what is the recommended way for doing something in Python?

Comment: There are books that not only teach Python, but also teach common idioms from the Python community and why they are used.  If you already know Python, you can look for web pages that just discuss Python idioms... here's my favorite: http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html  (But "Code Like a Pythonista" dates back to about 2006, so it doesn't mention the `with` statement).  Also, if you read a few questions and answers here on StackOverflow, people like me will be recommending the idioms.  :-)

Comment: I am using Python for a couple of years now, but I am not aware of most of those idioms (I haven't actually read any Python book, maybe that's why) :( This link looks great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> When you’re done with a file, call f.close() to close it and free up any system resources taken up by the open file.

You should always close a file after working with it. Python **will not** automatically do it for you. If you want a cleaner and shorter way, use a [`with`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement:

```
with open("filename.txt") as myfile:
    lines = [i.strip("\n") for i in myfile]
```

This has two advantages:

- It automatically closes the file after the `with` block
- If an exception is raised, the file is closed regardless.

Answer (score 0):

It *might* be fine in a limited number of cases, e.g. a temporary test. 
Python will only close the file handle after it finishes the execution.
Therefore this approach is a no-go for a proper application.

Answer (score 0):

When we write onto a file using any of the write functions. Python holds everything to write in the file in a buffer and pushes it onto the actual file on the storage device either at the end of the python file or if it encounters a `close()` function.

So if the file terminates in between then the data is not stored in the file. So I would suggest two options:

- use `with` because as soon as you get out of the block or encounter any exception it closes the file,

  ```py
     with open(filename , file_mode) as file_object:
             do the file manipulations........
  ```
- or you can use the `flush()` function if you want to force python to write contents of buffer onto storage without closing the file.

  ```
  file_object.flush()
  ```

**For Reference:** https://lerner.co.il/2015/01/18/dont-use-python-close-files-answer-depends/